# Send data to php file and pull stuff from data base based on that data not working objective c

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

In my application, the user has the ability to post something and others can comment on it. Anyway, to view the post you see the title of it on a tableview which than pushes to a detail view. That segue carries the post id. To display the comments, I must send the post id to a php file. I then pull data from the database based on that post id and echo it in a json array so objective c can read it and display it. My problem is that I am never echoing the data because either the post id is not getting transferred to the php file or something else is happening.

I use the same objective c code below in other files to send and insert data into database and it works fine so I am not sure what the problem is.

Here is my objective c:

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{

NSError *error;

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

}


 -(void) start{

NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kRecieveUrl];

[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, _post_id]];

[postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kRecieveUrl];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

[self getData:data];

}
```

And my php:

```
<?php


$db_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") 
or die("Our servers are down at the moment");
mysql_select_db("My DB") or die("Couldnt find db");


$post_id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE post_id='$post_id'";

$results = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_numrows($results);

mysql_close();

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
$rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
- (void)start {

  NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:RecieveUrl];
  [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, _post_id]];
  [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                     queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error) {
                             // do error handling
                           } else {
                             id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                             if (error) {
                              // do error handling
                              } else {
                               // do something with json
                             }
                           }
                         }];
}
```

Comment: do I get rid of the get data method?

Comment: yes, the data is returned in the completion handler

Comment: Ok so it did not work, however when I create an NSLog for the json array and echo, it says (null)

Comment: First I'd try to enter the formatted URL in your browser to check whether the PHP part works properly

Comment: When i do like this: http://localhost/filePath/displayComments.php?id=55   It works fine

Comment: I'm using this ObjC syntax in several projects. What does this line log (put it before the NSJSONSerialization line) `NSLog(@"result (%@): %@", [response MIMEType], [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Comment: It logs what the php file outputs. So it is partially working i guess

Comment: now i just need to display that output in my tableview

Answer (score 0):

You're using the GET method so just delete the line `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`, otherwise you would have to pass a dictionary containing the POST data

Comment: it cannot work. Either implement the appropriate NSURLConnectionDelegate methods or use the `sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                          queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
              completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response,
                                          NSData *data,
                                          NSError *connectionError))handler` method.

Comment: No i mean when i deleted that line it did not work. What are the methods i need to implement?